# syntax error on Ruby On Rails installation

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby, bashrc

I am trying to install ruby on rails on my me elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya.
and now i am seeing the following errors on my terminal. 
even if when i restart the terminal the errors shows on the first line on my terminal.

'bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: syntax error near unexpected token `PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168:`esacexport PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'

I hope you will help me. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't `esacexport` be `esac export` ? If the words are stick together your shell won't take it as an instruction

Comment: Thank You.

So should i open the  .bashrc file in text editor and edit that line on code ?

Comment: Yes, it's a perfectly editable file, this script is run every time you start a shell under your user, it is the place where you commonly put your environment variables declaration, like PATH in your example, by writing `export VARIABLE = /path/to/dir/or/file`. Just put a space between esac and export and you're good to go :)

Comment: I have make the changes

esac export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

and now it shows the following  errors
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: syntax error near unexpected token `export'
bash: /home/smehsan/.bashrc: line 168: `esac export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'

Comment: Did it do it? For some explanations, esac is the word closing the `case` instruction `case some code esac`

Comment: sorry i did not understand.

Comment: Hum that's weird... Can you paste here some lines of the file please?

Comment: Thank You
I have paste this on the gist. Please check this gist.
https://gist.github.com/ehsanatwork/eb36efe1d9c7e290265445a1b9679b81

Comment: You're welcome. Try putting a new line after `esac`

Comment: do you mean a new line break after  `esac`

Comment: Press the enter key ^^

Comment: Oh great, Now it remove from my terminal.
one more thing, if you don't mind can you please tell me, how can i remove everything related to ruby that i have installed as because i want to reinstall ruby on rails.

Comment: I don't know where Ruby is installed, but you might find it on Google, you're not the first who wants to remove Ruby ^^ don't forget to give me an upvote if your problem is resolved !

Comment: can you please tell me how can i give you a upvote?

Comment: There's an up arrow button left to my answer

Comment: i have already give you a upvote. and it will be diplayed after 15 reputation of mine. You are amazing. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh ok ^^ nevermind then